# Why does this python function output include the first variable's value?

Tags: python, function

As a total noob, I encountered the question below while trying to do some exercises online. However, I do not understand the logic here. There's a new function to add salary, but it also prints the first one. Why does the output include the 8000 while printSalary() is a new function command?

```
salary = 8000

def printSalary():
  salary = 12000
  print("Salary:", salary)
  
printSalary()
print("Salary:", salary)
```

The Output:

```
Salary: 12000
Salary: 8000
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: well first the salary is a global variable and inside the printSalary method salary is a local variable so when you first call the method it changes the global variable and uses the local one. and yes you can refer to to @luk2302 's link for more info

Comment: Try it out here - https://pythontutor.com/   you could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In python, whenver you define a variable inside a function, it is initialized as a local variable and then can only be used inside that particular function.

In your example, the `printSalary()` function doesn't update the global variable `salary` but rather makes a new local variable with the same name.  If you want to update the `salary` variable in global scope, you can use the `global` keyword.

Here's the code for your reference:

```
salary = 8000

def printSalary():
  global salary
  salary = 1200
  print("Salary:", salary)
  
printSalary()
print("Salary:", salary)
```

This will give the output as:

```
Salary: 1200
Salary: 1200
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt. You can learn more about this from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/).

Answer (score 0):

The exercise is meant to demonstrate global vs local variables. A local variable named "salary" is created and used in the function.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp